# Web dev - setup firebase firestore question

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, web-development-server

i asked here few questions before and i did always got help so here i am again,
im kinda new to HTML,CSS,JS and i just wrote some html- css -js code for single webpage and i need to add some data that i can manage (data base) i searched online and found firestore and good solution for me (if u recommand on other ways to use live-data on ur site ill be happy to hear)
anyway i opened firestore database and set everything in firebase website went to my project followed this instructions:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-9
and
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
and few videos online
i tried all methods in these websites and youtube and still i cant make this work i even tried to load my website on XAMPP (maybe its not related to my problem but i cant think of any more solutions) please help me figure it out and try to explain the details as much as u can so it will really clear this for me.

this what ive done now:
1.my project is in htdoc folder inside XAMPP
2.i run Apache module in XAMPP in port 8080
3.i use localhost:8080/Website/Main.html in google chrome to reach the website
4.used npm install firebase in visual studio code console
these are my files:
Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Calander </title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Calander.css">
</head>

<body">

    <div class="calander">

    </div>
    <script type="module" src="firebase.js"></script> 
    <script src="Calander.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from ".//node_modules/@firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from ".//node_modules/@firebase/firestore";


const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
    apiKey: "******************",
    authDomain: "******************",
    projectId: "******************",
    storageBucket: "******************",
    messagingSenderId: "******************",
    appId: "******************",
    measurementId: "******************"
});

  const db = getFirestore();
  
  import { collection, addDoc } from ".//node_modules/@firebase/firestore"; 

  try {
    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
      first: "Ada",
      last: "Lovelace",
      born: 1815
    });
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
  }
```

Comment: No one really know how to do it? pleaes help me.. im stuck hard even firebase support didnt answer me..

Comment: Are you facing any error? If yes, can you mention the exact error?